# Make container scroll when dragging in Safari HTML5

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

Building a draggable component using HTML5 Drag and drop API [source](https://web.dev/drag-and-drop/). I am rendering the elements inside a scrollable container. When I drag an item - the container scrolls fine in Chrome and Firefox. But in Safari the container does not scroll at all when I drag an item. Any thoughts/pointers?

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/cocipupoyo/edit?html,css,js,output)

```
// relevant css. 
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its a limitation as of now. Safari supports scrolling when something is being dragged (multiple gestures support I guess) but doesn't auto-scroll when you try to drag and move the draggable content. This may be the reason it doesn't scroll unless the user drags with mouse and scrolls at the same time using the keypad as discussed in the below thread:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/252081922

Comment: Note that the link is about Final Cut Pro, not about Safari.